# How to define XMLDocument as parameter to a Method

Tags: java, web-services

I have the below method syntax, which currently accepts a String as parameter.

```
public ServiceRequest parseInputXML(String XMLdocument) throws Exception 
{

}
```

Is it possible to define in such a way that the method (parseInputXML()) would accept a XMLDocument as input, rather than a String?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's *possible* to do.

```
public ServiceRequest parseInputXML(XMLDocument XMLdocument) throws Exception 
{

}
```

parseInputXML() will now take a parameter of type `XMLDocument` rather than `String`, but otherwise is identically useless.

However, I get the distinct feeling that this is not what you *really* want to ask.

What are you trying to do? What is the significance of the parseInputXML() method that makes you even ask this question?

Comment: I am using java , could you please tell me in which package does this XMLDocument  exists ??  Thanks

Comment: *"could you please tell me in which package does this XMLDocument exists ??"* No, because there are multiple such classes depending on which XML parsing library you use. You will have to know which variant you want to use. (Btw, since you are apparently using Eclipse, you should be able to mouse-hover over the type name and select to import the appropriate one.)